# Unknown crash with simple app

Tags: android

My Android app is crashing for unknown reasons. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText x1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idEdittext);
    TextView x2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idtext);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

on start method

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(this, "This is your first App :)) ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

this is a method for a button to be excuted when clicked

```
public void onClick() {
    String name = String.valueOf(x1.getText());
    Toast.makeText(this," Welcome " + name +"" +"to Android" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    x2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

when I run it, it crashes & says "unfortunately , your app has stopped"

Comment: What does logcat say about the crash? What Exception do you get ?

Comment: It didn't say any thing in the logcat ,, no exception revealed but it crashes !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call `findViewById` before creating the activity.

Change your code like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText x1;
    TextView x2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        x1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idEdittext);
        x2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idtext);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```